# When calling Robot framework custom library definition by passing integers as arguments it is trying to read as a image file

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, rpa, imread

This is my robot class file content

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ./robotautogui.py

*** Test Cases ***
move it
    move_mouse_to    600    200
```

and my custom python library file

```
import pyautogui

class robotautogui:
    def move_mouse_to(self, x, y, duration=0.0):

        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration)
```

but running this give error:

move it                                                               [ WARN:0@0.127] global loadsave.cpp:244 findDecoder imread_('600'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
move it                                                               | FAIL |

**OSError: Failed to read 600 because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format**

[image: OSError: Failed to read 600 because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format]

why is it calling imread (I believe it is image read function). The function is working in python when called directly. But it just don't work in robot framework.

I am trying to convert some python code to robot framework for some automation purposes. Just started and some codes where perfect for starters. But this I just don't know how to tackle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get from pyautogui is incorrect. Pyautogui requires integer or float values for x and y. Robot Framework variables are strings unless specified.

Workaround is to convert them to integer:

```
import pyautogui

class robotautogui:
    def move_mouse_to(self, x, y, duration=0.0):
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        duration = float(duration)
        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration)
```

Comment: That is entirely not what I was expecting. And thanks for solving this problem. Hope the Robot team sees this and fixes this in the next version.
Still, I am not convinced how it gets to read as imread() !
I mean can we use 
   "pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration)"
to point out image location on screen somehow then?

Comment: @mr.Luvji   Like Pekka said "Unless specified".  You can add normal python type hints and keyword arguments should be converted to correct type if you are running new enough robot framework

Comment: @rasjani I didn't know about RF library type hinting. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: @Pekka feature has been there since 3.1 if the docs are correct ;) https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#specifying-argument-types-using-function-annotations